# how to create a collapsing row for smarttable?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am trying to implement a collapsing row in my smarttable. This is a row that is only visible once the user wants to show some more detail. This is what it looks like now:

```
   <table st-table="displayed" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-ratio="20" st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
        <th st-ratio="20" st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
        <th st-ratio="10" st-sort="age">age</th>
        <th st-ratio="30" st-sort="email">email</th>
        <th st-ratio="20" st-sort="balance">balance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="show"/> {{show}}

    <tr ng-repeat="row in displayed">
        <td st-ratio="20">{{row.firstName}}</td>
        <td st-ratio="20">{{row.lastName | uppercase}}</td>
        <td st-ratio="10">{{row.age}}</td>
        <td st-ratio="30">{{row.email}}</td>
        <td st-ratio="20">{{row.balance | currency}}</td>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="show">
        <td>hallo</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
            <div  st-items-by-page="20" st-pagination=""></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Is there a way of displaying a collapsing detailrow for this table?

plunkr ref:http://plnkr.co/edit/8lSx2v?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

```html
<table st-table="displayed" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th st-ratio="20">#</th>
         <th st-ratio="20" st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
         <th st-ratio="20" st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
         <th st-ratio="10" st-sort="age">age</th>
         <th st-ratio="30" st-sort="email">email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="row in  displayed">
          <td>
            <button ng-if="row.expanded" ng-click="row.expanded = false" class="btn btn-xs btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></button>
            <button ng-if="!row.expanded" ng-click="row.expanded = true" class="btn btn-xs btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></button>
          </td>
          <td st-ratio="20">{{row.firstName}}</td>
         <td st-ratio="20">{{row.lastName | uppercase}}</td>
         <td st-ratio="10">{{row.age}}</td>
         <td st-ratio="30">{{row.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="row.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
          <td colspan="2">
              <b>Balance<br /></b>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" st-ratio="20">{{row.balance | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="text-left">
            <div st-items-by-page="5" st-pagination=""></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function with `ng-change`, and in there you expand the `displayd` array.

like I did in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W3B8TMqZgvYeN8nETvuh?p=preview):

```
        var limitVers = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            limitVers.push(createRandomItem());
        }
        var addedItems = [];
        for (var k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
            addedItems.push(createRandomItem());
        }

        var expaVers = limitVers.concat(addedItems);
        $scope.displayed = limitVers;

        $scope.update = function(show){
          show ? $scope.displayed = expaVers : $scope.displays = limitVers;
        }
```

Comment: it does not toggle display hide row?

Comment: doing  `{{displayed.length}}` tells me that it doesn't toggle. I don't know why.